# How to delete a notebook in Evernote for Android?

Tags: evernote

I accidentally create a duplicate notebooks using Evernote app. I want to delete one of them. When I open my Notebook list, the options that I can see are just 'rename notebook', 'move to new stack' and 'sharing setting'.  where can I find 'delete' option?

Answer (score 3):

To delete a notebook, you'll need to log in to the [webapp](http://www.evernote.com). Your notebooks will appear on the left side of the screen. moving your cursor over (or tapping, on your device) the notebook you wish to delete will show a triangle to click for a drop-list from which you can delete the notebook.

Edit: According to this link, you can't do it from the Android app yet. http://discussion.evernote.com/topic/29175-helpdelete-notebook-on-android/

Comment: OP wants to delete from app.

Comment: @roxan OP surely prefers that -- but if it's not possible from within the app, he'll probably gladly accept a work-around as well :)

Comment: @Izzy I'm pretty sure OP knows how to do such *common* task from webapp. If it's not possible from the app, IMHO that should be mentioned in answer while giving the alternative.

Comment: @Izzy Sorry, thought I did mention that.

Comment: @TheDoorkeeper Feel free to update your answer -- the more complete it is the better. It will even increase chances for upvotes (not using the app I cannot verify, so I have to leave this to others ;) Besides: No sorry to me, it was roxan who missed this :)

Comment: @roxan Sorry, thought I did mention that

Comment: @TheDoorkeeper haha There is no need to be sorry. :) cheers